# getJSON vs .open producing two different results when calling API

Tags: api, getjson

Trying to understand why one works and other doesn't. When user clicks the name, a new quote is displayed, but only under .getJSON does this work.  Under the .open method, a quote shows, but does not change after when the name is clicked. Why is this? both are using exact same api url and key.

[.getson method](http://codepen.io/max77p/pen/NxOVEG)

[.open method](http://codepen.io/max77p/pen/Yqwzev)

WITH .OPEN METHOD

```js
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

 $(".name").on('click', function() {

   responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
   $(".quote1").html(responseObject.quote);
   console.log(responseObject);

 });

 xhr.open('GET', 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/', true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Key", "fjZoisqRfomshkDSNH1AZLpFCS6gp1yVxU8jsn3fPleq6TIPeF")
 xhr.send(null);
```

WITH .getJSON METHOD

```js
$(".name").on("click", function(){
$.getJSON('https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/',{"mashape-key": "fjZoisqRfomshkDSNH1AZLpFCS6gp1yVxU8jsn3fPleq6TIPeF"}, function(json){
  
  console.log('json response: ', json);
$(".quote1").html(json.quote);
});
  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like when i am using .open i should be using onload with anonymous function to load a new quote every time user clicks the name. But I am not sure why that is, if someone can explain would be great!

```js
 $(".name").on('click', function() {
   
  var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload=function(){


   responseObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
   $(".quote1").html(responseObject.quote);
   console.log(responseObject);
  };
   xhr.open('GET', 'https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.mashape.com/', true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Mashape-Key', 'fjZoisqRfomshkDSNH1AZLpFCS6gp1yVxU8jsn3fPleq6TIPeF')
 xhr.send(null);
 });
```